# Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService',]

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I'm writing an android application that connect to my Google calendar. I've been using Google Sample and Docs to correctly use the classes and import the right Jars.

When I create a Java Project in Eclipse and try to `System.Out.print()` my calendar there is no problem and both my Id and my events are shown.
When I write same code for an android app (in `onCreate` lets say), using the same Jars Import, Eclipse sends me back with logCat error:

> "Could not find class 'com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService"

Any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the jar to your project setup. Just hover over the error in the class file and select "Fix Project Setup".

Answer (score 0):

That is because you referenced the requiered `.jar` files and haven't included them to your apk.

Place the requiered jar files in your project `\lib` folder

Follow this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/6eNj4avdfM0) for more info